# JSpinner getValue returns same value

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a `JSpinner` in a GUI.

I use the following code to `getvalue` of the spinner:

```
       JSpinner StarttimeSpinner = new JSpinner();
        Date starttime = new Date();
        starttime = (Date)StarttimeSpinner.getValue();
```

The `getValue` method always returns the very first value which I set in Spinner.

The scenario is:

1. I will enter value in spinner (e.g. 00:00:00) and click save (GUI will be closed program wont terminate) on which I `getValue` and store in a map.
2. The next time if I open GUI in same session and set some other value (e.g 11:11:11) for spinner and click save but this time I expect `getValue` should return 11:11:11 but it's giving 00:00:00.

Where am I making a mistake?

### Edit

This is how I set the value:

```
SpinnerModel Startmodel = new SpinnerDateModel();
StarttimeSpinner = new JSpinner(Startmodel);
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(time);
StarttimeSpinner.setValue(date);
JComponent editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(StarttimeSpinner,
        "HH:mm:ss");
StarttimeSpinner.setEditor(editor);
```

The variable `time` is `String`.

Comment: You need to show more code, particularly the code where you set the value of the spinner. getValue() returns the last valid value of the JSpinner. I'm betting you didn't set the value properly (i.e. get a reference to the model and set the value there).

Comment: @MarsAtomic I have added the setValue code

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).